# Getting Name of the form that sent request to the servlet

Tags: forms, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to retrieve the form name from a Java HTTPServletRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252125/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-form-name-from-a-java-httpservletrequest)

How can I get the name of the form that sent the request to the servlet, because I have two forms and I need to process them differently based on their names?

Answer (score 1):

You can't as-is. You need to add the form name as hidden input if you need to get its name. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252211/1012381) for more details